# Android Reverse Geocoding

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding

I'm trying to get an address from a location. I'm doing so inside a asynctask inside a Fragement. All the other code works fine (checking an API and setting some UI stuff based on it) but this section to do the geocoding just won't. I followed an example from elsewhere on StackOverflow (can't remember the exact topic).

```
 TextView locTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationText);
                Geocoder geocoder;
                List<Address> addresses;

                Double x = 55.971627;
                Double y = -3.602585;


                try
                {
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.ENGLISH);
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
                    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                    if (geocoder.isPresent())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "geocoder present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                        String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                        String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                        String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                        String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                        str.append(localityString + "");
                        str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                        str.append(zipcode + "");

                        locTxt.setText(str);



                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "geocoder not present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {}
```

When it gets to the if statement for geocoder.isPresent() is fails the if and just continues on with the rest of the program.

Comment: Do you have the internet permission added? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: @Andy Sorry had thought I had posted back on this thread. I got it solved. It's a problem with the emulator. Even when you set GPS coordinates for the emulator it doesn't run the GeoCoding code. Works fine on a physical device though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Android Emulator. Even when you set coordinates via the command line the emulator will not preform GeoCoding code and therefore fails on my check if GeoCoder present. Works just fine on a physical device.